# ImportError: cannot import name 'PostListView' from 'main.views'

Tags: python, django

hello guys I'm beginner in learning Django, I got this error when I try to import PostListView from .views

this project urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('/', include('main.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is my app main urls:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from main.views import PostListView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view, name="blog"),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

and this is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView


def blog(request):
     context = {
         'posts': Post.objects.all()
     }
     return render(request=request,
                   template_name='main/blog.html',
                   context=context)


class PostListViews(ListView):
    model = Post


def about(request):
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='main/about.html')
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name is defined as `PostListViews` instead of `PostListVew`. You  either need to change the class name, or the name you imported.